# Find child objects in list of parent objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Given a list of Parent objects that each have a list of Child objects, I want to find the child object matching a specific ID.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want the Child object having a specific ID:

```
List<Parent> parents = GetParents();
Child childWithId17 = ???
```

How can I do this using Linq?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you want:

```
Child childWithId17 = parents.SelectMany(parent => parent.Children)
                             .FirstOrDefault(child => child.ID == 17);
```

Note that this assumes that Parent's Children property won't be a null-reference or contain null Child references.

Comment: @Ani for null references you can add up two extra Where conditions.

Comment: @AkashKava: Sure, but there's no need to add them unless nulls were allowed by design.

Comment: Thanks, accepting this answer because I like the concise use of .FirstOrDefault.

Comment: I know this is old, but how would I select the parent based off the child results? So get the parent list if it's child list meets the condition.

Answer (score 7):

You can use SelectMany:

```
Child childWithId17 = parents.SelectMany(p => p.Children)
                             .Where(ch=>ch.ID==17)
                             .FirstOrDefault();
```