# How to get a list of all subobjects contained in a list of objects?

Tags: c#, linq

If you have a list of products and each product has a list of categories.

How do I get the list of cateories used by the products?

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

Product product1 = new Product();
product1.Categories.Add("Books");
product1.Categories.Add("Electronics");

Product product2 = new Product();
product2.Categories.Add("Dishes");
product2.Categories.Add("Books");

products.Add( product1 );
products.Add( product2 );
```

How Do I get a list "Books", "Dishes", "Electronics"

Comment: The question is different then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297528/find-child-objects-in-list-of-parent-objects-using-linq

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx)

```
var result = products.SelectMany(x => x.Categories).Distinct().ToList();
```

This is what SelectMany does and I quote MSDN.

`Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable(Of T) and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.`

Here is a working proof.

[image]